# Do I need to escape dash character in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to understand dash character `-` needs to escape using backslash in regex?

Consider this:

```
var url     = '/user/1234-username';
var pattern = /\/(\d+)\-/;
var match   = pattern.exec(url);
var id      = match[1]; // 1234
```

As you see in the above regex, I'm trying to extract the number of id from the url. Also I escaped `-` character in my regex using backslash `\`. But when I remove that backslash, still all fine ....! In other word, both of these are fine:

- [`/\/(\d+)\-/`](https://regex101.com/r/sJ5mX4/1)
- [`/\/(\d+)-/`](https://regex101.com/r/sJ5mX4/2)

Now I want to know, which one is correct *(standard)*? Do I need to escape dash character in regex?

Comment: I think that you only need to escape the dash when it is inside the `[]` not sure though.

Comment: Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you mean exactly? If I know the answer, then why should I ask it?

Comment: That's a good question! So why *have* you asked it, given that you've already demonstrated to yourself that you *don't* need to escape that dash?

Comment: @JorgeCampos and even then, only when it's not the first or last character (eg. `[a-z0-9_-]` allows alphanumeric, underscore and hyphen)

Comment: Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol now I'm sure :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You only need to escape the dash character if it could otherwise be interpreted as a range indicator (which can be the case inside a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)).

```
/-/        # matches "-"
/[a-z]/    # matches any letter in the range between ASCII a and ASCII z
/[a\-z]/   # matches "a", "-" or "z"
/[a-]/     # matches "a" or "-"
/[-z]/     # matches "-" or "z"
```

Answer (score 12):

`-` may have a meaning only inside a character class `[]`, so when you're outside of it you don't need to escape `-`