# How to strip all non-alphabetic characters (except hyphen) from string in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

```
Select dbo.[RemoveNonAlphaNumExceptSub]('aAbc123-4def5678ghi90 jkl#^.\')
```

- escaping '%[^a-z0-9-]%' returns aAbc123-4def5678ghi90jkl\
- before '%[-^a-z0-9]%' returns #.\
  adding in beginning, end they hyphen but it still gets stripped

[How to strip all non-alphabetic characters from string in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007697/how-to-strip-all-non-alphabetic-characters-from-string-in-sql-server)

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaNumExceptSub]( @Temp VarChar( max ) )
Returns VarChar( 1000 )
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar( 50 )
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9]%'
    While PatIndex( @KeepValues, @Temp ) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff( @Temp, PatIndex( @KeepValues, @Temp ), 1, '' )

Return @Temp
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping it by placing a backslash in front of the regex pattern like: `'%[^a-z0-9\-]%'`.

Alternatively, you can place the hyphen as the first character in the pattern like `'%[-^a-z0-9]%'`

Feel free to [refer to this post for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589074/regex-should-hyphens-be-escaped), or [refer to this post too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536590/do-i-need-to-escape-dash-character-in-regex/35536652).

Answer (score 0):

this finally works '%[^a-z0-9-]%'